# What's the most pythonic way to load a matrix in ijv/coo/triplet format?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn

My input file is in ijv/coo/triplet format with string column names, eg:

```
Apple,Google,1
Apple,Banana,5
Microsoft,Orange,2
```

Should result in this 2x3 matrix:

```
[[1,5,0], [0,0,2]]
```

I can read it manually by putting the column names to dictionaries and create a scipy sparse coo_matrix with that dict mapping to IDs. I would like to get it in scipy sparse or pandas dataframe in the end.

Is there any more pythonic way to do that? Pandas can only read csv, there is `scipy.io`, but they don't have coo format either. So if there is no library what would be the most pythonic way to get it into `scipy.coo_matrix` or `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: a coo matrix should have column/row corresponding to a coordinate. What are your coordinates ? For example , does (Apple,Google ) correspond to some x,y which has value 1 ?

Comment: "does (Apple,Google ) correspond to some x,y which has value 1" yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an unambiguous mapping from the row/column names to some indices (it is not important whether "Apple" is "0", or "1", just that it is represented by a number, hence this won't exactly match your result, but it should not matter). In this example, `'info.txt'` contains

```
Apple,Google,1
Apple,Banana,5
Microsoft,Orange,2
```

Here is one way to achieve a coordinate matrix:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

input = np.loadtxt( 'info.txt', delimiter=',' , dtype=str)
rows,cols,data = input.T
map_rows = { val:ind for ind,val in enumerate( np.unique(rows) ) }
map_cols = { val:ind for ind,val in enumerate( np.unique(cols) ) }
result   = coo_matrix( (data.astype(float),( [map_rows[x] for x in rows], [map_cols[x] for x in cols]) ) )
```

Now you have the mappings and result

```
print map_rows
#{'Apple': 0, 'Microsoft': 1}
print map_cols
#{'Banana': 0, 'Google': 1, 'Orange': 2}
print result.toarray()
#array([[ 5.,  1.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.,  2.]])
```

Comment: Thank you @dermen, I like how you create the mapping (this is definitely more pythonic as I had it before). It still feels quite verbose, though.

I guess we could define `def idmap(l): u = np.unique(l)   im = { u[x]:x for x in range( u.shape[0] )  }    return map( lambda x: im[x], l )` to save three lines.

Comment: Id assume you want to keep the mapping dictionaries around for later use, which you would loose with function calls.. But that depends on the overall purpose and extent of the code. You can use use ```enumerate``` to eliminate the need to have the ```u_rows``` and ```u_cols``` variables. Also, you can apply the mappings directly in the argument of ```coo_matrix``` to save space, but that is a bit messy.

Comment: I decided to use functions and return the mappings alongside with the mapping dictionaries. Thank you very much for your answer! I hope this functionality will be picked up in sklearn/pandas, but meanwhile I guess it's not getting easier :) I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv for this:

```
matrix = []
with open('input_file', 'rb') as csvfile:
     input_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     for row in input_reader:
         matrix.append([row[0], row[1], row[2]])
```

Then you will have this in `matrix`:

```
[['Apple', 'Google', '1'], ['Apple', 'Banana', '5'], ['Microsoft', 'Orange', '2']]
```

If you want a numpy matrix from that, I believe that according to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) this should work:

```
nm_matrix = np.matrix(matrix)
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't clear enough in my original question, my goal was to get it into an object which I can then use in scikit-learn/pandas. Such as a numpy matrix, DataFrame or coo_matrix.

Comment: I begin understanding that asking an unambiguous question is hard :) Unfortunately this doesn't yield the desired output. Yes, one gets a numpy matrix, but the format works a bit different: rowName,columnName,value. So the desired output would be as a numpy matrix: [[1,5,0],[0,0,2]]. I will add this to the example.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how you get `[[1,5,0],[0,0,2]]` from your input.

Comment: Value 1 is in the row with the name/id Apple and the column with the name/id Google. The cell with the row id Apple and column id banana contains the value 5. etc.

Comment: I still don't understand, sorry. How should the program know what is what? What is the algorithm? Maybe someone else will be able to help you.

Answer (score -2):

Will `[line.split(",") for line in open(input_file)]` work?

That code would read every line from the file, split into comma-seperated rows, and collect the results in a list.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the overall goal is to get it into numpy/coo_matrix/DataFrame data structure.